# Add Text values of Columns B7:b and E7:e and place value on J7:j, just on ONE worksheet

Tags: vba, excel, addition, calculated-columns

Ok I have the first part working with one major problem.  When I run the code below it will display a text value for every page in the workbook.  I only need it to display a value in "J" on the "initiating devices" page.  The other pages have different column headings.  Also it only will work when the macro is run manually,  I would like to know if it could be run as the user enters the status of a devices,  this will update values on another page in real time.  Here is the code I have been using so far with limited success

```
Sub calctestvalues()

Dim lng As Long
lng = Cells(Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Row
Range("J7:J" & lng).Value = Evaluate("=B7:B" & lng & "&E7:E" & lng)

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following will find the last row in Column B on your "Initiating Devices" sheet and write to the correct ranges.

```
Sub CalcTestValues()
    Dim wb As Workbook
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim lastRow As Long

    Set wb = ThisWorkbook
    Set ws = wb.Sheets("Initiating Devices")

    lastRow = ws.Range("B" & ws.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
    ws.Range("J7:J" & lastRow).Value = Evaluate("=B7:B" & lastRow & "&E7:E" & lastRow)

End Sub
```

If you want this to fire when a user is entering data, you'll need the `Worksheet_Change` event. Here is a good reference to get you started: [Worksheet Change Event: Automatically Run Excel Macros When a Cell Changes](http://www.ozgrid.com/VBA/run-macros-change.htm).

Comment: I'm looking up the information now on using the worksheet change event code.  Would I simply then remove the Sub CalcTestValues() line from the above code and place in a worksheet change event code In its place.  This of course would go onto the "initiating devices" page I'm assuming.  I will play around a bit and see what happens thanks again for the help.

Comment: Assuming CalcTestValues now works the way you want, just call it from the worksheet_change handler.

Comment: I Tried to add the code to the worksheet "INITIATING DEVICES" and when added it crashes the whole program excel 2013.  I simply added the code above and used.  Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range).  I actually added it to the end of code as there are several other codes using the same change event.  I can not post the whole code on here as it is not allowed in comments. when i have that in my code it crashes the whole program when data is entered.

Comment: Your best bet is to create a new question and ask about getting the worksheet_change event part working. Is your main question answered here? (writing to one sheet only)

Comment: yes the main question was answered thank you for your help, I will open up a new question for the newest problem.  Thank you